# Best practice for Android MVVM startActivity

Tags: android, mvvm, android-databinding, decoupling

I am building an Android App using MVVM and DataBinding. And I have a function inside my ViewModel that starts an Activity.
Is it okay to have an onClick call inside a ViewModel?

Like this.

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public void onClick(View view, long productId) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("productId", productId);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

And in my XML:

```
...
android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onClick(v, viewModel.product.id)}">
```

Or would it be a best practice to move it to the View and call it from EventBus or Rx and have only POJO in my ViewModel?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The answer to your question is what is your goal?

If you want to use **MVVM** for separation of concerns so that you can unit test your `Viewmodel` then you should try to keep everything that requires a `Context` separate from your `Viewmodel`. The `Viewmodel` contains the core business logic of your app and should have no external dependencies.

However I like where you are going :) If the decision which Activity is opened lies in the View, then it is very very hard to write a JUnit test for it. However you can pass an object into the `Viewmodel` which performs the `startActivity()` call. Now in your **Unit test** you can simply mock this object and verify that the correct `Activity` is opened

Comment: "The Viewmodel contains the core business logic of your app and should have no external dependencies." - I think it will always have external dependencies. I don't see a point in using ViewModel without databinding and it is android specific, just check example import: "import android.databinding.ObservableBoolean;"

Comment: @LLL, You are right to some extent. The question is what do want to achieve. For me the most important thing is testability. If I have a dependency to `View` or `Context` I can only test via *Robolectric*. These tests are slow and require a lot of overhead. So what I am looking for is plain Unit test that run in a fraction of the time an are easy to implement. The dependency to the databinding library does not diminish this.

Comment: @Kaskasi, So there is any way to implement such functionality. I don't want to keep Context in my ViewModel class as it can create Memory leaks. Neither i want to pass any reference. So if i want to pass some String resource from view to viewModel or i want to call a method in View to launch some activity then how do i implement it.

Comment: @SainiArun You can do something similar to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883415/android-mvvm-with-programmatic-ui-customization/41220631#41220631 So what you want to do is pass an abstraction into your ViewModel or Presenter. That abstraction(interface) could have a method `String getString(@StringRes int id)`. And in the concrete implementation of that interface you would implement `getString` and could delegate this to context. getString(). This way the ViewModel only sees an abstraction  which you could mock for testing

Comment: @Kaskasi, Thanks for the response. Actually i already know this approach and i am using it as well. I am not really concerned with testing. My only concern is to not use any reference to view because that can lead to memory leak and i don't want that. So tell me if we use an interface implemented in view and referenced by ViewModel to get or set data in View, would it lead to memory leak?

Answer (score 14):

The way I do it is, in your ViewModel:

```
val activityToStart = MutableLiveData<Pair<KClass<*>, Bundle?>>()
```

This allows you to check the class of Activity started, and the data passed in the Bundle. Then, in your Activity, you can add this code:

```
viewModel.activityToStart.observe(this, Observer { value ->
    val intent = Intent(this, value.first.java)
    if(value.second != null)
        intent.putExtras(value.second)
    startActivity(intent)
})
```

Comment: thanks, but Not work me. can you explain, please? How can we use the method in onClick of view tag in XML?

Answer (score 10):

That's absolutely perfect to put it inside `ViewModel`, however you need to set your `ViewModel` from `Activity`/`Fragment`.

Here are some links you can follow to learn MVVM architecture.

[Approaching Android with MVVM](https://labs.ribot.co.uk/approaching-android-with-mvvm-8ceec02d5442)
[Android MVVM](https://github.com/manas-chaudhari/android-mvvm)
https://github.com/ivacf/archi
[People-MVVM](https://github.com/erikcaffrey/People-MVVM)
[MVVM on Android: What You Need to Know](http://willowtreeapps.com/blog/mvvm-on-android-what-you-need-to-know/)

Comment: Most of these examples have context referrences in the ViewModel. To me this is not true MVVM.

Comment: @MwBakker I believe the most important things about MVVM is the separation of logic between layers, as a result, View should be responsible for handling UI and nothing more! So, In this case, I believe View Model having a reference to application context is less harmful than forcing the view to do none UI tasks. BTW there are many other cases that we may need context in ViewModel that's why Android has a version of ViewModel that has context!

Comment: thought you were supposed to have no android packages in the viewmodel?

Answer (score 3):

As the principle of MVVM points out that only View (activity/fragment) holds reference to the ViewModel and the ViewModel shouldn't hold reference to any View.

In your case, to start an activity, I will do like this:

**MyViewModel.class**

```
public class MyViewModel {
public static final int START_SOME_ACTIVITY = 123;

 @Bindable
 private int messageId;

 public void onClick() {
  messageId = START_SOME_ACTIVITY;
  notifyPropertyChanged(BR.messageId); //BR class is automatically generated when you rebuild the project
 }

 public int getMessageId() {
        return messageId;
 }

 public void setMessageId(int message) {
        this.messageId = messageId;
 }

}
```

And in your **MainActivity.class**

```
@BindingAdapter({"showMessage"})
public static void runMe(View view, int messageId) {
    if (messageId == Consts.START_SOME_ACTIVITY) {      
        view.getContext().startActivity(new Intent(view.getContext(), SomeActivity.class));      
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    finish(); //only call if you want to clear this activity after go to other activity
}
```

finally, in your **activity_main.xml**

```
<Button    
  android:onClick="@{()-> myViewModel.onClick()}"    
  bind:showMessage="@{myViewModel.messageId}" />
```

Comment: In viewmodel value stays same so it might start activity again and again

Answer (score 3):

As per the data binding documentation.
There are 2 ways to do that:

1- [MethodReferences](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#method_references) : You have to pass the view as a parameter to the function, or you will get a compile time error. 
If you will use this way do a separate class as example here that handle such events.

MyHandler

```
public class MyHandler {
   public void onClick(View view, long productId) {
        Context context = view.getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, ProductDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("productId", productId);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

XML

```
<data>
        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="com.example.ViewModel"

        <variable
            name="myHandler"
            type="com.example.MyHandler" />

    </data>android:onClick="@{myHandler.onClick(viewModel.product.id)}">
```

2- [Listener bindings](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/expressions#listener_bindings) : You don't need to pass the view as the example here. 
But if you want to startActivity make your viewModel extends AndroidViewModel and you will use the applicaion object.

ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    public void onClick(long productId) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getApplication(), ProductDetailActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("productId", productId);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

XML

```
android:onClick="@{() -> viewModel.onClick(viewModel.product.id)}">
```

Comment: In part 2, `context` is not actually defined. Assuming you want to use `getApplication()` as the context, you unfortunately have to set FLAG_INTENT_NEW_TASK, otherwise you will crash. (There were some recent versions of Android which did not crash, but this was considered a bug). See https://stackoverflow.com/q/3918517/3175580

Comment: you can pass it easly through the xml. android:onClick="@{(v) -> viewModel.onClick(v,viewModel.product.id)}">
.. code: public void onClick(View v,long productId) ... v.getContext()

Answer (score 2):

in MVVM we can use `LiveData` for this Event . because ViewModel is Alive when the `activity/Fragment` destroyed! So the best way is `LiveData`

1.Create Class Call `Event` and `Extends` It from `ViewModel`:

```
class Event : ViewModel() {
```

2.create field from LiveData :

```
private val _showSignIn = MutableLiveData<Boolean?>()
```

3.create method for this private field:

```
val showSignIn: LiveData<Boolean?>
    get() = _showSignIn
```

4.create method that you can setValue on your liveData:

```
 fun callSignIn() {
        _showSignIn.value = true
    }
```

**The final Event Class :**

```
import androidx.lifecycle.LiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.MutableLiveData
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel

class Event : ViewModel() {

     private val _showSignIn = MutableLiveData<Boolean?>()

        val showSignIn: LiveData<Boolean?>
            get() = _showSignIn

        fun callSignIn() {
            _showSignIn.value = true
        }
```

5. Call the method in your activity or fragment :

THe instance from eventViewModel :

```
 private val eventViewModel = Event()
```

call the observe :

```
 eventViewModel.showSignIn.observe(this, Observer {
            startActivity(Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java))
        })
```

and if you use the `data binding` you can call `callSignIn()`  in `onClick` XML :

in Variable tag:

```
<variable
            name="eventViewModel"
            type=packageName.Event" />

 android:onClick="@{() -> eventViewModel.callSignIn()}"
```

**NOTE: do not forget set binding in your `activity/fragment` :**

```
  binding.eventViewModel = eventViewModel
```

---

I search for the best way and Find it. I hope to help someone

Comment: Be careful with this approach. 
If you press the button, the activity will start, then you go back and rotate the screen, the LiveData value will be sent again, so the activity will start again unexpectedly.
So, with this kind of events, you should use other approach, search for SingleLiveEvent or EventWrapper.

Comment: Yes @fernandospr, If we try setting the value of _showSignIn to false during the onStop of the activity, it will resolve the issue you addressed. Use the boolean inside the active observer and allow only to open activity when it's true.